# How to get String and Int input together in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

So I'm just experimenting with input, and I am just wondering how to get integer and string input in the same line. For example:

```
age, name = input().split()    #if input is like the name
```

doesn't work
How do I get input no-matter if its float, integer or string. Thanks.

Comment: The first line makes no sense, but the second does. So the first shouldn't work, and the second should.

Comment: `int(input()).split()` most certainly *doesn't* "work"…!?

Comment: I don't think you can get two different types of data in single line.you can typecast it in the next line using age = int(age)

Comment: Yep, sorry the first line doesn't work. Yes, I'm trying to get 2 different types of data in a single line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
age, name = input().split()
age = int(age)
```

This would be the easiest - just do the thing in two lines.

For two numbers, you cannot split an int. So you have to iterate through the result list and then apply int:

```
num1, num2 = [int(elem) for elem in input().split()]
```

> How do I get input no-matter if its float, integer or string

If you want to automatically check what is it, I'd recommend just making a function and trying different things.

And I mean literally "trying", `try/except` blocks: `try` int, if it fails `try` float, if it fails try something else, at the end return the input string.

Comment: FWIW: `num1, num2 = map(int, input().split())` would be my approach for the second snippet…

Comment: Ty. I just really *really* like comprehensions. :D